# Regex to truncate trailing zeroes

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to construct a single regex (for Java) to truncate trailing zeros past the decimal point. e.g.

- 50.000 → 50
- 50.500 → 50.5
- 50.0500 → 50.05
- -5 → -5
- 50 → 50
- 5.5 → 5.5

Idea is to represent the real number (or integer) in the most compact form possible.

Here's what I've constructed:

```
^(-?[.0-9]+?)\.?0+$
```

I'm using `$1` to capture the truncated number string.

The problem with the pattern above is that 50 gets truncated to 5. I need some way to express that the `0+` must follow a `.` (decimal point).
I've tried using negative-behind, but couldn't get any matches.

Comment: `^(-?[\.0-9]+?)(\.0+)?$`

Comment: Like so: [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/aJ5kC1/1) ?

Comment: Which language you were using?

Comment: Is there always a decimal point?

Comment: Note that all regex approaches will break down if the String represents a number in a format that uses a different decimal separator (or uses the dot character as a grouping separator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution could be using built-in language-specific methods for that task.

If you cannot use them, you may use

```
^(-?\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*?)0+|\.+)?$
```

And replace with `$1$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH5qA8/1). Adjust the regex accordingly. Here is the explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `(-?\d+)` -Group 1 capturing 1 or 0 minus symbols and then 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.0+|(\.\d*?)0+|\.+)?` - An **optional** (matches 1 or 0 times due to the trailing `?`) non-capturing group matching 3 alternatives:

  - `\.0+` - a decimal point followed with 1+ zeros
  - `(\.\d*?)0+` - Group 2 capturing a dot with any 0+ digits but as few as possible and matching 1+ zeros
  - `\.+` - (**optional branch, you may remove it if not needed**) - matches the trailing dot(s)
- `$` - end of string.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/5nsjCO):

```
String s = "50.000\n50\n50.100\n50.040\n50.\n50.000\n50.500\n50\n-5";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?m)^(-?\\d+)(?:\\.0+|(\\.\\d*?)0+|\\.+)?$", "$1$2"));
// => [50, 50, 50.1, 50.04, 50, 50, 50.5, 50, -5]
```

Comment: @WingPoon: What do you expect to get if the input is `-5`? There is no decimal part in it. As far as I remember, you need to remove *trailing zeros in the decimal part*, or did you change your mind and now want to match all up to the trailing zeros?

Comment: You must add the requirement to the question. Use [`^(-?\d+)(?:\.0+|(\.\d*?)0+|\.+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/wH5qA8/1). What is the method/code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

For a general regex which should do the trick:

`^\d+?0*\.??\d*?(?=0*?[^\d]*$)`

You can replace the caret and dollar sign with whatever your boundaries should be. Those could be replaced by whatever you would expect around your number.

basically:

`/d+?` non-greedy match for any number (needs at least 1 number to start the match)

`\.*??` optional match for a decimal. Prefers to match 0 occurrences

`\d*? (?=0*?[^\d]*$)` - non-greedy match for a number, but would stop at the 0 which is proceeded by a non-number

**EDIT**: I just realized the original expression also trimmed the last zero on integers, this should work. I added the option 0 match to catch that